# How can I to load and query local json data in Flutter Mobile App

Tags: json, load, flutter

Here is my **key:value** paired local json. I need to load and later I need to use for query.
So, how can I to load and query local json data in Flutter Mobile App?

```
{
  "currency.01": "United State USD",
  "currency.17": "British Pound GBP",
  "currency.33": "Euro EUR",
}
```

Comment: You can use https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/shared_preferences

Answer (score 36, accepted):

add your JSON file to the `pubspec.yaml`

```
  assets:
    - assets/config.json
```

and then you can use `rootBundle` to load it

```
import 'dart:async' show Future;
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;

Future<String> loadAsset() async {
  return await rootBundle.loadString('assets/config.json');
}
```

also take a look at this [full example](https://github.com/nisrulz/flutter-examples/tree/master/load_local_json) 
and for querying convert your JSON data into a [LIST](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-core/List-class.html) and then you have a lot of search methods like the [where](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-core/Iterable/where.html) method

Comment: I have a value as "01", so I need to also make query. Either I need to change my json data or if you know how to make query with existing one I will appreciate.

Comment: Thanks @Raouf, I will test it.

Comment: Thanks! Helped me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

rootBundle typically is just part of the answer. I would do jsonDecode as well to return an actual json format.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

Future<String> loadAsset() async {
  return jsonDecode(await rootBundle.loadString('assets/config.json'));
}
```

then on your main, you can now load this to a `List<dynamic>` for a list formatted json object.

```
List<dynamic> response;
response = loadAsset();
```

then from here you can now access your values by,

```
print(response['currency.01']);
```

output: United State USD